# Disable touchscreen for boot

Tags: boot, kernel, touchscreen

I have a laptop with a faulty touchscreen. It is most likely why I get kernel panic during the boot.

How can I disable the touchscreen during the boot?

Comment: Do you know what generic driver is used for the touch interface?

Comment: unfortunately I do not. How can I check it?

Comment: Ok, I was able to boot Windows on this laptop and identified the Windows driver that causes Windows to fail: Intel Dynamic Platform and Thermal Framework Manager - when I install this driver I always get a blue screen and need to revert to previous system restore point.

Comment: I've noticed a strange thing: when I boot using legacy boot the system hangs with kernel panic, but when I use UEFI boot I can boot into Ubuntu Live USB. Strange, is not it?